# Align vertically and horizontally H1 and Button

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I can't find solution for this problem. When I have 1 element to center I usually do position relative on parent and on child I just do:

```
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
-ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
transform: translateY(-50%);
```

However when I have two or more elements it can be a struggle. Can someone help me to center H1 and button?

I have similar problem with vertical align in this example. I did manage to center elements ( img, p, button) here but I know mu solution isn't really elegant 'cause I used paragraph around button to make it work. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2x4ge.jpg)

Here is my attempt to make it work

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <section class="work">
    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-lg-6">
        <div class="content">
          <div class="image">
            <img src="" alt="">
          </div>
          <h3>Subtitle</h3>
          <div class="center">
            <p>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Primary</button>
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-lg-6">
        <div class="content">
          <h3>Subtitle</h3>
          <p>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Primary</button>
          </p>
          <div class="image">
            <img src="" alt="">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
.work {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.content {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  width: 95%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
.image {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 130px;
  height: 130px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
.work h3 {
  text-align: center;
}
.work p {
  text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`text-center` which is a bootstrap `class` will center your `H3` and `button` so no need of using `text-align:center` css if you have already a built in class of bootstrap, While `image` instead of wrapping it around `p` tag a little bit of improvement is required in your css to make `image` centered.

```css
.work {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.content {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  width: 95%;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right: auto;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 15px;
}

.image {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 130px;
  height: 130px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 10px auto;            /* To make image center */
}
```

```html
<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">


<section class="work">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6">

      <div class="content text-center">     <!-- Text Center -->
        <div class="image">
          <img src="" alt="">
        </div>
        <h3>Subtitle</h3>
        <div class="center">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Primary</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-6">
      <div class="content text-center">   <!-- Text Center -->
        <h3>Subtitle</h3>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Primary</button>
        <div class="image">
          <img src="" alt="">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Sorry, but you misunderstood my question, I edit it for more clarification. My question is how to align H1 and Button, and 2nd sub-question (with picture added) is how to align H3, Button and Image. I used paragraph wrap over button to align it but I know that's not the right way.

Comment: @RadioGirl My bad, I have updated the answer Do let me know  if my new answer matches your requirement!